# Definition of large integer value

Tags: c++, casting, int64

I have a project where I deal with large numbers (ns-timestamps) that don't fit in an integer. I therefore want to to use e.g. int64_t and am currently writing a test case (yes!).

To check the behaviour for large number, i started with something like

```
int64_t val = 2*std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
qDebug() << "long val" << val;
```

which returns

```
long val -2
```

(same as if i define val as int).

But if I write

```
int64_t val = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
val *= 2;
qDebug() << "long val" << val;
```

I get

```
long val 4294967294
```

which looks correct.

So for me it looks as if the `2*max()` is first stored in an integer (truncated in this step) and then copied to the `int64`. Why does this happen? The compiler knows that the result is of type `int64` so that it the `2*max()` should fit directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So for me it looks as if the `2*max()` is first stored in an integer (truncated in this step) and then copied to the `int64`

This is absolutely correct. According to the language specification, when all parts of an expression fit in an `int`, the computation is done in integers. In your case, both `2` and `max()` do fit in an `int`, so the multiplication is done in integers, causing an overflow.

> The compiler knows that the result is of type `int64` so that it the `2*max()` should fit directly.

The result to which an expression is assigned does not matter in this situation: the expression itself directs the way it is calculated. You can achieve the same result by casting the `max()` to `int64`:

```
int64_t val = 2*(int64_t)std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```